# printing every page of a VSTO project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio and I'd like to have a paper copy of my project. There are c# libraries, aspx files, javascript files, css... I'd like to print everything at once to my pdf printer. I know I can do this one file at a time but I was wondering if there is a magic button for that?

Thanks.

Comment: you really want to have a *paper* copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just looked for the same thing a couple weeks ago, there isn't a perfect solution that I could find... This question was asked before:

[Visual Studio: Printing all source files in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683759/visual-studio-printing-all-source-files-in-a-solution)

With the answer pointing to an old macro from MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973240.aspx

Another search turned up a result for a commercial product that claims to do what you're looking for, however, I haven't tried it and was unable to even find pricing:

http://submain.com/products/prettycode.print.net.aspx

Hope that helps, in the end I just opened all the files at once and just closed each one as I printed it.  Not at all ideal, but it got the job done at the time.