# Print entire Project source code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, printing, code-formatting

I need to print the source code of a VS2010 project (all files, around 400). Is there any way to automate this task?

Any option is good: whether it is directly to a "physical" printer or to a virtual printer (PDF printer).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Printing all source files in a solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683759/visual-studio-printing-all-source-files-in-a-solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built into VS. But you can find a macro that does the job at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973240.aspx.
Also, a modified version is loacted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/683835/337294

Answer (score 1):

A Project file is an XML file. You can extract the filenames and then pipe them to any tool you like. If you have any unix-like tools on your Windows system you can do the following to print all .cpp files:

```
grep -o "\".*\.cpp\"" MyProject.vcxproj | xargs cat
```