# Print all code listings from a C++ project

Tags: c++, printing, ide

I need to print the source code of a project that consists of a bunch of .h and .cpp files (I need to hand it in to my teacher). Is there an IDE or a program that lets you print (or export to PDF or Latex) all the files at once, possibly keeping the syntax highlighting? I tried with XCode and Visual Studio but they just allow to print one file at a time.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683759/visual-studio-printing-all-source-files-in-a-solution and see if it helps.

Comment: Pretty Code Printing says the project file is unsupported (appearently it doesn't work with C++ code). As for the Macro, I get an E_FAIL COMException at
projitem.Document.PrintOut()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU tools like [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) or [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) can convert source code into postscript files that you can then print or convert to pdf.  They support syntax highlighting for various languages, and they can bundle up multiple files into the same document.

Comment: a2ps is really a great tool! It does exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With the linux box you may try:

```
grep '#include <' *.{hpp,h,cpp,c} | uniq > output.cpp
grep -v '#include' *.{hpp,h} >> output.cpp # This line may cause problem if .h relies on each other and you maybe will have to list files manually
grep -v '#include' *.{cpp,c} >> output.cpp
```

And than open output.cpp in editor which supports exporting of hilighted code (vim, gedit...) or paste it on portal like pastebin :P